# Get Entity Linq expression result to DataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following code using Entity framework:

```
 PEPSModel.PEPSEntities context = new PEPSModel.PEPSEntities();
    var v = context.ApplicationList_assignedReviewer(userID);
```

How can I want to get the result (of var v) in Datatable?

Comment: I want to apply sorting on GridView

Answer (score 1):

You must create `DataTable` manually if you want it. The better way is not using DataSet API (imho you should avoid it at all costs) and execute the query every time with correct `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending`.